# Need to add size restriction on a version with carrierwave uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, image-uploading

```
class ImageUploader < BaseUploader
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  version :crop do
   process :crop_with_params
  end

  def crop_with_params
   manipulate! do |image|
    image.crop "#{model.crop_w}x#{model.crop_h}+#{model.crop_x}+#{model.crop_y}!"
   image
  end
end
```

---

I am able to get the image size in `crop_with_params`, but don't know how to trigger the size validation on view.

Answer (score 0):

If you need add restriction for size of downloaded file, you should add validation ([file_validators](https://github.com/musaffa/file_validators)), like

```
validates :avatar, file_size: { less_than: 2.gigabytes }
```

accoding to [carrierwave wiki](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/how-to:-validate-attachment-file-size)

if you need resize it, you should add resize params to your uploader

```
  version :crop do
    process resize_to_fit: [100, 100]
  end
```

**EDITED**

If you need validate image after resize just add this parameter to config according to [DOCUMENTATION mini-magick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick#image-validation)

Comment: Ok, but i want to put size(i.e. 20kb or something) restriction on `crop` version and if not so then trigger an error with message.

Comment: use this gem https://github.com/musaffa/file_validators it will help you

Comment: i already have the size validation on the original version of image, but i want to put a size cap on the cropped version created by mini-magick and trigger a error message.

Answer (score 0):

I accessed the image version(created by minimagick on server before upload) in a callback of my model and then used it to put a size restriction.

```
mount_uploader :image, uploader
validate :xyz

 def xyz
    if image.version.present? && image.version.size.to_i < max_size
      errors.add :image, "select more large image."
    end
  end
```